# x,y,z size of collada object in Three.js

Tags: three.js, collada

assume i have a cube as a collada object (in .dae format). i need to know the size of this cube and later will be computed or calculated
so, how can i get the x,y,z size(for example height, width) of it? is there maybe something like dae.size? 
or maybe i could use boundingBox (from http://threejs.org/docs/58/#Reference/Core/Geometry )?

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
geom.boundingBox()
```

but, i dont really understand how to use this bounding box with Three.js yet.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Computation of Collada object bounding box has been discussed here:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1843

Comment: I have opened issue issue https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3370 for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the x,y,z size you could simply use this:

```
var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( colladaModel );
console.log( box.min, box.max, box.getSize() );
```